# In the MLB, is someone known as being the ultimate journeyman?

Tags: mlb

I'm thinking there must be a player whose career consisted of a collection of single seasons, each with a different team.

I know there are relief pitchers like this.  I'd be more interested in learning about a position player.

I tried to search for players who fit this mold on Baseball Reference.  One that came to mind was Arthur Rhodes.  His career was front loaded with a long stint at Seattle, and the second half saw him hop around.

I'm sure there's got to be someone who is known as being the ultimate journeyman.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for this format, at least in the way it seems to be most likely to be interpreted.  If the question were, "What player is known as The Big Hurt", it would be fine - that's a question with a specific answer, because The Big Hurt is the specific nickname for Frank Thomas.  But it sounds like you're asking a question that really depends on opinion, because there isn't a player whose nickname is "The Ultimate Journeyman" - instead it's more of a "list some players who played for a lot of teams", which isn't really on topic here.

Comment: Ricky Henderson is an interesting case: despite being a Hall-of-Famer, he played for 9 different teams. He was with five of them for one season or less, and though he played for Oakland for 14 years, that was split into *four* separate stints. From the age of 34 to 44, he never spent more than one-and-a-half seasons with a team at one time. (And this is only considering his MLB career, which was followed by two seasons in the Atlantic League and one in the Golden Baseball League.)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard that term applied to a single player.  That's unlikely to be a fan-favorite, because you're looking for someone that was never with any team very long and wasn't good enough to be kept around.

My vote would be for [Matt Stairs](https://www.mlb.com/player/matt-stairs-122644).  Although he did play for Oakland for 5 consecutive years, all the other teams were max 2 years.  19 seasons in the majors, 12 different teams.

Matt also holds the MLB record for pinch hit homers with 23.

Kenny Lofton played for 11 different teams, but was such a force for Cleveland during his prime that I don't think he fits your request.  There's probably several players with only one year with each team (or less), but that didn't hold up for long and are quite forgettable.

I remember [Paul Bako](https://www.mlb.com/player/paul-bako-132720) during his stint with the Astros.  He played for 11 teams, no more than 2 consecutive years with any, but I think backup catcher may be similar in feel to relief pitcher.

Comment: Nice answer.  Didn't realize that about Stairs or Lofton.